# HTML DOM: Why childNodes[i] cannot be correctly get for "<li>" elements when there are line breaks?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The puzzle occurs when I am trying *HTML DOM*.

To make it simple, the code is as following:

======================================================

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <script>
  function jsTest()
  {
   var x = document.getElementById("fruits");
   var y = x.childNodes[2].innerHTML;
   alert(y);
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <ul id="fruits">
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Banana</li>
  <li>Pear</li>
  <li>Orange</li>
 </ul>
 <button onclick="jsTest()">TRY</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**As you can try, when clicking the "TRY" button, it alerts "undefined", but why ?**

**I have tried the following modifications:**

(1). var y = x.childNodes[2].innerHTML;      >>>     var y = x.childNodes[1].innerHTML;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <script>
  function jsTest()
  {
   var x = document.getElementById("fruits");
   var y = x.childNodes[1].innerHTML;
   alert(y);
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <ul id="fruits">
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Banana</li>
  <li>Pear</li>
  <li>Orange</li>
 </ul>
 <button onclick="jsTest()">TRY</button>
</body>
</html>
```

This time, it works, with alert "Apple".
Similar trials are to change childNodes[1] to childNodes[0] (Result: undefined), childNodes[2] (Result: undefined), childNodes[3] (Result: "Banana"), childNodes[4] (Result: undefined)...

**(2).I also tried "children[i]" instead of "childNodes[i]", it works fine (i=0 || 1 || 2 || 3 )!**

For example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <script>
  function jsTest()
  {
   var x = document.getElementById("fruits");
   var y = x.children[2].innerHTML;
   alert(y);
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <ul id="fruits">
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Banana</li>
  <li>Pear</li>
  <li>Orange</li>
 </ul>
 <button onclick="jsTest()">TRY</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**(3). Keep all the "li" tags in one line without line breaks, it works normally now for childNode[i] (i=1 || 2 || 3 || 4) !!**

For example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <script>
  function jsTest()
  {
   var x = document.getElementById("fruits");
   var y = x.childNodes[3].innerHTML;
   alert(y);
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <ul id="fruits">
  <li>Apple</li><li>Banana</li><li>Pear</li><li>Orange</li>
 </ul>
 <button onclick="jsTest()">TRY</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Remark: All the tests above are tried out in Google Chrome/ IE 11/ Firefox/ Opera/ Win10 Edge, etc.

**So my question is:
Is it somehow an "Unwritten Rule" when applying childNodes[i] function on "li" elements ?
OR
Is it just a BUG for childNodes[i] function ?**

I am a Chinese self-learner with learning period around 2 months, I'm afraid this 1st question I raised here is just too simple, I've tried in searching for similar questions here and on Google, but failed :(

Thanks for your answers anyway :)

Comment: Text nodes are included in [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) collection. It's not an "unwritten rule", the linked docs says: "_childNodes also includes e.g. text nodes and comments._" If you need element nodes only, use [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) collection.

Comment: `<li>x</li><li>y</li>` is two nodes. `<li>x</li>[linebreak]<li>y</li>` is THREE nodes, because the line break is included as a text node.

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks a lot for your quick answer !  "line break is included as a text node", yep, but it's still weird since it alerts "undefined" for childNodes[2] when there are line breaks for li elements.

Comment: I'd highly recommend always try logging things out to debug things yourself, before asking people on here to do the same. By logging out `x.childNodes` you would see that there are extra items in that object, the text nodes between the LI elements.

Comment: @mike652638: It's not weird. If it had HTML, then it wouldn't be a text node; it would be an element. The `.innerHTML` property doesn't make sense for text nodes.

Comment: Uhm yes, thank you Squint, the main mistake I made is using "inneHTML" here, I should apply "textContent" instead !

Comment: @mike652638 FYI, `next/previousSibling` also includes a text node, if present. To get a next or previous element only, `next/previousElementSibling` can be used.

Comment: Hi Teemu, ok, got it. Thanks for the additional remarks, you are so nice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change :

```
var y = x.childNodes[2].innerHTML;
```

To :

```
var y = x.children[2].textContent;
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <script>
  function jsTest()
  {
   var x = document.getElementById("fruits");
   var y = x.children[2].textContent;
   alert(y);
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <ul id="fruits">
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Banana</li>
  <li>Pear</li>
  <li>Orange</li>
 </ul>
 <button onclick="jsTest()">TRY</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Ehsan for your help. Yeah, I tried it out, it works.

Comment: @ mike652638, mark it if help you.

Answer (score 0):

`if (!y[i].nodeValue)` filters out the undefined's

```js
function jsTest()
{
  var x = document.getElementById("fruits");
  var y = x.childNodes;

  for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if (!y[i].nodeValue){
      console.log(y[i].innerHTML);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <ul id="fruits">
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Banana</li>
  <li>Pear</li>
  <li>Orange</li>
 </ul>
 <button onclick="jsTest()">TRY</button>
</body>
</html>
```